# String toLowerCase and Contains in one statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do both ( toLowerCase and includes ) in one go like below?

```
let x = this.state.outreach.arival.toLowerCase(includes("likely"))
```

Comment: `toLowerCase().includes(...`.

Comment: Are you trying to check against a string or an array? What is the sample value of `this.state.outreach.arival`

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal: Both have `includes` (now), and it seems fairly clear in this case it's a string...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - True. But suspect whether if it is an array then OP might want to check against lowercase of array values.

Comment: So you want a case-insensitive search of one string inside another? will the passed string always be lowercase? Maybe you want to `trim()` the strings? In these realms, there are too many approaches to such a seemingly simple problem as to implement a general function for that in JS; write your own little utility-function that covers your specific intent, and DRY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toLowerCase()` and `contains` are two methods applied for `strings`.

So, you need to use them in the following way:

```
let x = this.state.outreach.arival.toLowerCase().includes("likely")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this :

```
let x = this.state.outreach.arival.toLowerCase().includes("likely");
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "do both."

**If you don't need to keep the lowercase version** and just want to use it, you just chain the calls:

```
let x = this.state.outreach.arival.toLowerCase().includes("likely");
```

Alterately you could use a regular expression without case-sensitivity (by using the `i` flag):

```
let x = /likely/i.test(this.state.outreach.arival);
```

**If you want `this.state.outreach.arival` to end up in all lowercase**, then you need to assign back to it. The clearest way is:

```
this.state.outreach.arival = this.state.outreach.arival.toLowerCase();
let x = this.state.outreach.arival.includes("likely");
```

Although you can do it with an inline assignment (yuck):

```
let x = (this.state.outreach.arival = this.state.outreach.arival.toLowerCase()).includes("likely");
```